# How to convert repeating rows into columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrays

I have data in Google Sheets that looks like

```
    A        B
1 Name:  John Smith
2 Email: john@smith.com
3 Name:  Dan Jones
4 Email: dan@jones.com
... many rows
```

which I'd like to get into this format:

```
   A            B
1 Name        Email
2 John Smith  john@smith.com
3 Dan Jones   dan@jones.com
...
```

This is different from just a straight transpose because we're dealing with repeating sets of rows that need to be repeatedly transposed into columns.

What's the best, fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query formula:

```
={{"Name";QUERY({B1:B},"where Col1 is not null and  not Col1 contains '@'")},
  {"Email";QUERY({B1:B},"where Col1 contains '@'")}}
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thanks. Just going with this answer as it is the cleanest solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

```
=index(B:B,2*row()-1)
```

and copy downward.  In  **D1** enter:

```
=index(B:B,2*row())
```

and copy downward:

[image]

If you need to enter the formulas below row#1, replace:

```
row()
```

with:

```
rows($1:1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm just going for the voted answer because it's just a bit cleaner with not having to copy downward the formula.

Comment: @DanielMay  I agree with you completely! The marikamitsos post is really cool.  I am going to up-vote it myself.